# Excel fomularbar shows correct Value, Sheet shows VALUE error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, worksheet-function

Here is the data I have been using, data format all General:

```
Name    Address
Adam    250
Mohame  150
Adam    220
Adam    423
Yasir   240
Ibrahim 236
Adam    242
```

Index formula cell B11 contains the formula to match value in cell A11:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$A$11,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$A$11,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

The formula bar shows correct values, but cell B11 shows `#VALUE!`.

Comment: you may be able to get an answer on SO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems to be working for me. If you aren't using it properly (i.e. by not using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), you should be getting blanks.

One thing you can do is to make the formula a bit shorter by using `IFERROR()` like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$A$11,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2),"")
```

Comment: hi thank for the reply, i have use new work sheet but still not working for me, by the way which version of excel is you using is there any thing related to Version issue

Comment: @AdamArsh I have Excel 2007. What exactly do you have as values and worksheets?

Comment: Hi Jerry:  I just create new sheet and entered only the sample values above and the data formate is general. no other data in the sheet.but still not showing the value, i am using Excel 2007 too

Comment: @AdamArsh I'm not sure why you're getting the error. See the spreadsheet I made [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Adam.xlsx).

Comment: Hi Jerry just looked at you file, the values are there

Comment: Hi Jerry just looked at you file, the values are there. if i edit the formula then the value disappears. for example if i put the rage from B8 to B9, or if change any part and replace the same value it disappear for example i changed A1 to A2 and back to A1 the value disapears in it, but i copy exatlly to other cell it diappears. I wanna change the rage cox my data is from A1 to A10000. any idear

Comment: @AdamArsh After you change the formula, **do not** press Enter. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hi Jerry: Ctrl+Shift+Enter works perfectly, Thanks for the reply and i would appreciate if you could tell me more abt why just enter dont works thanks once again

Comment: @AdamArsh This is because the formula is an array formula; i.e. it returns more than one value in a single cell and excel cannot display this normally. Pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter will make it choose one value (either the first result or the only one without error). You can try pressing F9 instead of Enter to see all the different values returned :)

Comment: Hi Jerry thank Quick reply and now i understand the reason :)